# Thread waiting/blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, throttling, blockingqueue

I have a normal UDP process that sends and receive data from other server.

2 requests having the same reception IP address and reception port has a possiblity of data loss/switching. As a solution, All requests will be save to a map(single instance), if there’s incoming request that has the same reception ip And port will wait for the other transaction to finish and to be removed in the map before map insertion and start the UDP process of request.

Question is what is the best way to do the waiting process. I tried `CountDownLatch` but initialization has a given count and unknown number of requests might come and it is not the best method to use.

Comment: Hi! Can you please structure your question by insterting empty lines in between logical paragraphs? This is very hard to read. Also, spare us the last two phrases (don't thank us in advance, and it's clear that you're open for suggestions). These are completely meaningless and just negatively prolong your question.

Comment: `Question is what is the best way to do the waiting process.` What waiting process you are looking for? Do you have any code can explain it?